# Do spinal and peripheral nerves associate with hebbian learning?

Tags: neuroscience, neurology, nervous-systems

For instance, if a musician frequently makes a series of actions, neurons that are involved in such sequence should also associate inside the spine - according to "neurons that fire together wire together".
If so, to what extent?

Comment: Similar to: [Do neurons involved in reflex movements process information or they just transmit a signal?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21515/7001)

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg Not sure I gather the similarity there?

Comment: @BryanKrause Both questions ask if PNS performs processing on its signals.  This one is more specific in asking about learning (learning is only brought up in comments in the other question).  Note that I'm not suggesting it's a duplicate.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I think the question you've linked is more about the complexity of reflex arcs, not their origin. My question is whether short circuits in the peripheral nervous system can be learned via experience. (I've looked in the comment section. Yes, they brushed this topic, but I don't think it was awnsered).

Comment: My intuition is that some motor skills are learned in the periphery, because it would make evolutionary sense if an animal could execute a series of movements with shorter latency. But on the other hand there are only so few nerves, so the capability to form meaningful structures is probably very low when compared to the brain.

Comment: @OskarZdrojewski I would then revise your question to ask specifically about what you want to ask about, and preferably show some of your prior research and understanding of the problem. For example, are you aware of local networks in the spinal cord? Can you also be sure to distinguish between *nerves* and *neurons*? As it is, I would have answered that you misunderstand Hebbian plasticity from the shortened and inaccurate form "neurons that fire together wire together" which is **not** Hebb's postulate. However, I don't think this answer would actually address the question you have in mind.